# css height:100%; a div halfway down the page

Tags: jquery, html, css

So I currently have:

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li id="last"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

All the `<li>` elements have a property `border-right:1px solid black` and I want `li#last` to be an empty `<li>` element that will go all the way to the bottom of the page so the `border-right` doesn't suddenly stop.

Visual example:

[image]

On the left is what I'm currently getting, on the right is what I want to achieve. Notice the last `<li>` element still pushes the `border-right` all the way to the bottom.

Comment: Could you post a jsfiddle?

Comment: just set the border on the ul instead of the li, and then extend ul to 100%

Answer (score 2):

You can give the `<ul>` border instead of the `<li>`s. Just extend it's (and it's parents) height to `100%` to it stretches down the whole page.

```
html, body, ul {
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    margin: 0; /* No margins to interfere */
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none; /* No bullets */
    background: #f00; /* A background, to see it */
    padding: 0; /* No padding */
    display: table; /* Shrinkwrap */
    border-right: 1px solid black; /* And the border */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LfsLv/